# AWS Cloudwatch only shows "1" in log monitoring?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

After more complex examples didn't work with the same outcome, I'm following the basic tutorial from here: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountingLogEventsExample.html

I have set it up, and see the displayed dashboard:
[image]

I just send 1000 requests to the endpoint, however I'm only seeing "1" as the graphed metric.

```
ab -c 20 -n 1000 -T application/json -p data.json -m POST "<my-url.com>"
```

[image]

I'd like to see accurate reflection of request counts, what errors am I making in configuring cloudwatch metrics?

Comment: This is kind of vague. Can you provide a bit more insight into what you are trying to test? Also are you running the Cloudwatch agent to ship metrics to Cloudwatch? Are you running the AWS CLI commands to push events? ie 

```aws logs put-log-events \
  --log-group-name MyApp/access.log --log-stream-name TestStream1 \
  --log-events \
    timestamp=1394793518000,message="Test event 1" \
    timestamp=1394793518000,message="Test event 2" \
    timestamp=1394793528000,message="This message also contains an Error"```

Comment: @MichaelQuale I'm not running a cloudwatch agent. The fargate container's stdout/stderr is picked up by cloudwatch, and everything cloudwatch-related I do via the AWS UI. Including setting up and viewing the graphed metrics.

Comment: Ok, so that helps identify the services you are using. did you use a custom IAM profile attached to your ECS service? Does your services task def have a logs tab?

Comment: sounds like you might be graphing the average/max/min statistic rather than sum

Comment: Can you update the graph in your question to show min, max, average and sum (4 different lines)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution might have been to specify "0" as the default value (the default value is missing by default). I somehow go to see meaningful metrics, but when the metric value is "1", it shows I'm getting about 0.05 of them. Whatever the unit is (concurrency, maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be missing the log configuration from your ECS fargate task definition.

Make sure you have that setup. ie;

```
"logConfiguration": {
            "logDriver": "awslogs",
            "options": {
                "awslogs-group": "/ecs/my-app-logs",
                "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                "awslogs-stream-prefix": "myapp-prd-"
            }
        }
```

Take a read here, 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html#enable_awslogs

You must have the correct IAM permissions for logs:CreateLogStgream and logs:PutLogEvents attached to the IAM profile you use to run your ECS containers